# Possible history behind photograph related to 1962 Sino-Indian War

Tags: united-states, india, 1960s, tibet, 1950s

I came across the following image in an archive of photographs related to the [1962 Sino-Indian War](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sino-Indian_War):

[image]

I have posted a [question](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/50542/aircraft-identification-for-a-possible-60s-70s-usaf-transport-aircraft) for identification of the aircraft.

The text in the archive seems to suggest the photo depicts evacuation of [Tibetan refugees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Refugees_in_India#Tibetan_refugees) by the USAF. However, the location of the photograph and the destination, is not stated.

Google search for "`US evacuation tibet`" and other combinations, do not yield any related results.

Google Image search for the image has also not yielded any positive results.

**Observations**:

- There seems to be a military person (wearing a beret and appearing to be dressed in uniform, slightly away from the lineup of the kids, and also holding a child) who appears to be of Indian origin and thus most probably Indian Army.
- The source of the archive seems to suggest very strongly that the photograph was taken in India.

**What is the history behind this photograph?**

Answer (score 8):

I'd say, from the partial emblem on the front, that the aircraft was part of the USAF [322d Airlift Division (Combat Cargo)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/322d_Airlift_Division) in 1962-3.

According to [this article](http://www.bharat-rakshak.com/IAF/history/1962war/1263-leh-airlift.html) the "[322 Air Division] sent a squadron of C-130 Hercules to India just after the end of the 1962 hostilities with China".

To give credit where it's due, @TomMcW & @Gerry on the Aviation board got the right [aircraft](http://www.c-130.net/aircraft-database/C-130/airframe-profile/6315/). It was assigned to the [40th Airlift Squadron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/40th_Airlift_Squadron) which was part of the 332d AD. The 40th AS, sent 12 C130s to New Delhi, India to [aid the Indian armed forces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/40th_Airlift_Squadron#Sino-Indian_War), where they served for a year.

Comment: I agree the emblem seems to indicate 322d Airlift Division...